# How to I return the correct value from the callback within a String.prototype.replace() method?

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, string, foreach

I have this code, it should return `"BLABLABLALBLA CAT COOL DOG CAT"`, but it returns `"BLABLABLALBLA C COOL D P C"` now...

The error in the code is in the callback of the [String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) method.

Currently I'm just returning `match` which is the values that have been filtered by the replace method. In the callback I want to check if D,P or C do exist in the array of `abbreviations`, if they do then the script should print the abbreviation out, otherwise it should not print out anything, because I do not want to display any words that have less then 3 characters, IF they don't exist in the abbreviation array.

The callback of the replace () method should return dog for d, cat for c and for p the should only return an empty string ("") as p does not exist in the `abbreviations` array.

**Please find attached code:**

```js
const abbreviations = [
      { abbreviation: "d", expansion: "dog" },
      { abbreviation: "c", expansion: "cat" },
      { abbreviation: "h", expansion: "horse" }
    ];
    
    const testStringOriginal = "      blablablalbla,  / c  coOL @ d p  233c    ";
    
    const filterPattern1 = /[^a-zA-Z]+/g; // find all non English alphabetic characters.
    const filterPattern2 = /\b[a-zA-Z]{1,2}\b/g; // find words that are less then three characters long.
    const filterPattern3 = /\s\s+/g; // find multiple whitespace, tabs, newlines, etc.
    
    const filteredString = testStringOriginal
      .replace(filterPattern1, " ")
      // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter
      .replace(filterPattern2, match => {
        console.log("typeof: ", typeof match);
        abbreviations.forEach( item => {
          if (abbreviations.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
            if (match === item.abbreviation) {
              console.log("match YES!");
              console.log("match", match);
              console.log(
                "abbreviation in the object: ",
                item.abbreviation
              );
              return item.expansion; // return DOG, CAT or HORSE (if any match)
            } else {
              console.log("match - NO!");
              return "";
            }
          }
        });
        return match;
      })
      .replace(filterPattern3, " ")
      .trim() // remove leading and trailing whitespace.
      .toUpperCase(); // change string to upper case.
    console.log("ORGINAL STRING:" + testStringOriginal);
    console.log("CONVERTED STRING:" + filteredString);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're returning the replacement from the wrong function (`forEach` callback). You need to make `forEach` update an external variable and then return that, or simply use `.find` for the same:

```js
const abbreviations = [
    {abbreviation: "d", expansion: "dog"},
    {abbreviation: "c", expansion: "cat"},
    {abbreviation: "h", expansion: "horse"}
];

const testStringOriginal = "      blablablalbla,  / c  coOL @ d p  233c    ";

const filteredString = testStringOriginal
    .replace(/\b\w{1,3}\b/g, match => {
        let abbr = abbreviations.find(x => x.abbreviation === match);
        return abbr ? abbr.expansion : '';
    });

console.log("CONVERTED STRING:" + filteredString);
```

Comment: @georg you the man! I will update the post with the full code.